# Sending SNS notification when an instance is stopped

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch

At some point in a day, one of my instances gets stopped and I am trying to send an SNS notification at that time.

I can do it in multiple ways:

1.) Create an alarm on the metric StatusCheckFailed_Instance and when this reaches Insufficient_Data state, i configure it to send an SNS notification.

2.) I can write a lambda script (put_metric_alrm) to create it for me and send it when state changes to Insufficient_Data.

My problem while doing this is the notification is being sent once a day if my instance is stopped for days. Instead, I want a notification to be sent **only** **when** it gets **stopped**.

How can I do this? Please suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [CloudWatch Events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html); you can create a new 'rule' such that an event will trigger on EC2 instance state-change notifications for a given instanceid where the state is 'stopped'. When the event is fired, you can then invoke an SNS topic to get notified of the change.

**Here is an example configuration:**

- Service Name: EC2
- Event Type: EC2 Instance State-change notification
- Specific state(s): stopped
- Specific instances: Your Instance ID
- Targets: Your SNS Topic Name

**The same example, as seen in the CloudWatch Events console:**

[image: CloudWatch Events Web Console]

Simply subscribe your SMS or email to the SNS topic, and you'll get notified when this instance enters the stopped state.

**See also:**

- [AWS API Documentation - PutRule](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchEvents/latest/APIReference/API_PutRule.html)
- [AWS CLI Documentation - aws events put-rule](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/events/put-rule.html)